# How to automatically add .com at the end in an HTML input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I'm trying to get an HTML input form field to automatically insert a ".com" suffix in HTML, but I also want the user to be able to edit the ".com" into whatever domain that they want. Any tips on how I should go about on this?

Comment: All inside a single input?

Comment: Correct. All inside a single input.

Comment: Unfortunately, they want it to be customize-able by entering rather than selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by **smart cheating**!
***[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/wonigo/3/edit?html,css,js,console,output)***

- Create two `contenteditable` SPANs, one for the *name* and the other
  for the *domain*.
- Than create a real `input` but set it as `hidden`.

Got the idea?

When the **user modifies the contenteditable** SPANs...
you simply **send both values to the hidden input**.

On form submit the hidden input's value will be sent to the server.

```js
$('.webaddress-span').each(function(){
 var $fake = $(this).find("span"),
     $real = $(this).nextAll(".webaddress-input").first();
 function getNameAndDomain(){
  $real.val( $fake[0].innerHTML +'.'+ $fake[1].innerHTML );
 }
 getNameAndDomain();                  // Do it on DOM ready,
 $fake.on("input", getNameAndDomain); // and on input
});



$("form").on("submit", function(evt) {   // Just to test
  evt.preventDefault();
  alert( $(this).serialize() );
});
```

```css
.webaddress-span{
  display:inline-block;
  border:1px solid #aaa;
  min-width:150px;
  background:#fff;
}
.webaddress-span span{
  display:inline-block;
  vertical-align:bottom;
  min-height: 1.2em;
  min-width: 0.3em;
  transition: background 0.5s;
  padding-left: 4px;
}
.webaddress-span span + span{
  padding: 0 4px 0 0;
}
.webaddress-span span:hover,
.webaddress-span span:focus{
  background: hsla(200, 70%, 50%, 0.2);
  outline:none;
}
.webaddress-span span {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
} 
.webaddress-span span br {
  display:none;
}
.webaddress-span span * {
  display:inline;
  white-space:nowrap;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <span class="webaddress-span">
    <span title="name" contenteditable>website</span>.<span title="domain" contenteditable>com</span>
  </span>

  <input hidden class="webaddress-input" name="domain_name" type="text">

  <br><input type="submit" value="Test form">
</form>
```

**NB:** The above still needs some tweaking to prevent enter key, spaces, etc, but you got the general idea.

Comment: Holy crap, you went beyond what was needed! You sir, ARE AWESOME!

Comment: @BrianSu it's not a super-perfect solution (as I've said) but is quite a nice trick.

Answer (score 2):

On the `blur()` event of the input check if the user has entered a domain, if not add a default one. I wrote a quick example (it's not perfect as some domains may not be recognized but it should give you the general idea)

**Example**

```
$("#myTextBox").on('blur', function (event) {
    var input = $(this).val();
    if (!input.match(/.*\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/)) {
        $(this).val(input + ".com")
    }
});
```

[Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/zksrxt3j/1/)

Comment: why on blur? why not on `input`. Also use `this.value` instead of `$`

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, I used `blur` as personal preference but you're right, you could use `input` as well. Thanks for the suggestion about `this.value`, I didn't realize that would work